# Change axis in histogram Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, histogram, axis

I have an array A defined as

```
A = [1 0 1 1 0 1 2 3 1 2 3 ];
```

I want to make histogram of this array. I have tried with

```
hist(A)
```

But the problem is it shows value 1 is 5 times, 2 is 2 times and so on. But I want like it as at position 1 value 1, at 2 value is 0 , at 3 value is 1 and so on.

Comment: Please explain more about the desired output. According to your description, the output is the exact definition of the array A..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hist` counts the number of occurances of each value in the input* and uses those for the height of the bars. This is why the output is what you mention. What you want, however, is just [`bar`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bar.html) because your input `A` already *is* a histogram.

```
bar(A);

%// Add some histogram labels
xlabel('Index')
ylabel('Frequency')
```

[image]

*This isn't technically correct since it depends on the bins, but for this specific input it is the case.